# jQuery and range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am making simple HEX to RGB / RGB to HEX converter and I have problem updating values with range input. On manual input everything is how it should be but when I move slider value is not updated until I move other one or input something on the page. for example if you move slider to 255 (any color) it should result that color to be FF but I am getting FA until I move another one then first one change to FF. I also have number input that need to be sync with slider and maybe is problem between them.

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="255" class="rgb-slider" id="rgb-r-slider" spellcheck="false" value="255">
<input type="number" min="0" max="255" class="rgb" id="rgb-r" value="255">
```

JS

```
$('.rgb-slider').on('input change', function() {
    $('#rgb-r').val($('#rgb-r-slider').val());
    $('#rgb-g').val($('#rgb-g-slider').val());
    $('#rgb-b').val($('#rgb-b-slider').val());
});

$('.rgb').on('input change', function() {
    $('#rgb-r-slider').val($('#rgb-r').val());
    $('#rgb-g-slider').val($('#rgb-g').val());
    $('#rgb-b-slider').val($('#rgb-b').val());
});
```

and here is JSFiddle file

https://jsfiddle.net/9qynd4pn/9/

Comment: Your `jsFiddle` doesn't contain code, just markup.

Comment: I don't really sure that "input change" is a valid event, just write "change"

Comment: @Kashkain yes, `input` is a valid event.

Comment: @Kashkain input and change are valid events. You can use "on" to bind them both like that.

Comment: I've updated the `jsFiddle` and it seems to work just fine? https://jsfiddle.net/9qynd4pn/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not opti but it work well ;)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.rgb-slider').on('input change', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".rgb").val( $(this).val() );
      updateHexaInput();
  });

  $('.rgb').on('input change', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".rgb-slider").val( $(this).val() );
    updateHexaInput();
  });
});

var updateHexaInput = function() {
var str = "";
 $('.rgb').each(function() {
   str += parseInt($(this).val(), 10).toString(16);
  });
  $("#hex").val( str.toUpperCase() );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <section id="color-converter" class="color-converter">

    <!-- HEX Input -->
    <div class="hex-group">
      <input type="text" id="hex" spellcheck="false" value="FFFFFF"><span></span>
    </div>
    <!-- HEX Input End -->

    <!-- RGB Input -->
    <div class="rgb-group">
      <p>R:
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" class="rgb-slider" id="rgb-r-slider" spellcheck="false" value="255">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" class="rgb" id="rgb-r" value="255">
      </p>
      <p>G:
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" class="rgb-slider" id="rgb-g-slider" spellcheck="false" value="255">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" class="rgb" id="rgb-g" value="255">
      </p>
      <p>B:
        <input type="range" min="0" max="255" class="rgb-slider" id="rgb-b-slider" spellcheck="false" value="255">
        <input type="number" min="0" max="255" class="rgb" id="rgb-b" value="255">
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- RGB Input End -->

  </section>

</body>
```